# Confusion regarding BJT voltage gain

Tags: bjt, verification

I learnt from youtube the gain from this circuit is as below where it just take
$$A_v=\frac{r_c}{r_e'}$$
[image]

while today I doing my revision encountered this question
[image]

and the answer provided as above.
[image]

I have no problem in understanding how the input and output resistance is obtain but confuse with what I learnt in youtube clip about the gain. For clarification is the gain actually is just simply the ratio of input resistance to the output resistance at the collector side? So this is the actual calculation? While the youtube clip above using approximation since

$$\beta r_e'$$ is far less than 220kohm and 47kohm so it is ignore in the calculation?

Also the input impedance as seen from the signal source after the approximation will be 200re' and the output impedance as seen by the signal is rc=200(510||10k) as well so the actual gain reduce to $$A_v=\frac{r_c}{r_e'}$$ where the beta value is cancel out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about voltage gain, the first thing to keep in mind is that it's not a question about, "If I apply \$5\:\text{V}\$ to the base, will I get \$10\:\text{V}\$ at the collector, so this is a voltage gain of 2?" It's about, "If I apply a tiny wiggle of the quiescent voltage at the base, how much larger will the tiny wiggle be at the quiescent voltage at the collector?" These are two completely different questions. One is a DC operating point question. The other is an AC voltage gain question.

I'm saying that just to make sure we are on the same page about your question, because I can't tell from what you write. So I may as well make it explicit.

So, with that in hand, here's what happens regarding a tiny AC wiggle of the quiescent voltage at the base:

1. Since the base-to-emitter voltage is nearly constant for our purposes (we can assume this is true for sufficiently small wiggles), the emitter voltage responds directly by moving in the *same* direction. If the base moves upward, then the emitter is pulled upwards, in response. Likewise, in the other direction. The emitter *follows* the base.
2. The voltage wiggle now appears at the emitter without changing magnitude. This wiggle at the emitter causes a change in current in the emitter resistor. Without the bypass capacitor involved, you'd divide the wiggle by the emitter resistor to work out the emitter's current wiggle, which would cause an equivalent current wiggle in the collector resistor. But in this case, it is bypassed by a capacitor which is taken to be a "dead short" at AC (for educational purposes, anyway.)

So what happens, then? Where does that emitter wiggle go if the capacitor essentially grounds it out?

In this case, it is the Shockley diode equation that comes into play. It was always in play, before. It's just that with large enough emitter resistors, it's not nearly so important.

I started this out by writing, *"Since the base-to-emitter voltage is nearly constant..."* Well, it's not actually constant. For small-signal BJTs, the emission coefficient (think of it as a *quality* figure) is \$\eta=1\$ (which is good), so it can be ignored for now. In that case, the important equation is (the base-emitter voltage includes both base current and collector current):

$$V_{_\text{BE}}=V_T\cdot\ln\left(\frac{I_{_\text{E}}}{I_{_\text{SAT}}}+1\right)$$

That's a large-scale model. What we want to know, instead, is, *"How do small \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$ changes affect small changes in \$I_{_\text{E}}\$?"* Or, conversely, *"How do small \$I_{_\text{E}}\$ changes affect small changes in \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$?"*

Here, we need calculus:

$$\begin{align*}
D\bigg[V_{_\text{BE}}\bigg]&=D\left[V_T\cdot\ln\left(\frac{I_{_\text{E}}}{I_{_\text{SAT}}}+1\right)\right]\\\\
\text{d}\,V_{_\text{BE}}&=V_T\cdot D\left[\ln\left(\frac{I_{_\text{E}}}{I_{_\text{SAT}}}+1\right)\right]\\\\
\text{d}\,V_{_\text{BE}}&=V_T\cdot\frac{\text{d} \,I_{_\text{E}}}{I_{_\text{E}}+I_{_\text{SAT}}}
\end{align*}$$

The BJT model parameter, \$I_{_\text{SAT}}\$, is negligible (on the order of picoamps or femptoamps), so it can be discarded. This leaves:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{d}\,V_{_\text{BE}}&=V_T\cdot\frac{\text{d} \,I_{_\text{E}}}{I_{_\text{E}}}
\\\\
\frac{\text{d}\,V_{_\text{BE}}}{\text{d} \,I_{_\text{E}}}&=\frac{V_T}{I_{_\text{E}}}
\end{align*}$$

That can be treated as a *dynamic resistance* at the emitter, \$r_e^{\,'}=\frac{V_T}{I_{_\text{E}}}\$, or propagated back with appropriate use of \$\beta\$ to the base as \$r_\pi=\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot \frac{V_T}{I_{_\text{E}}}\$. (There's another related term, \$g_m=\frac{I_{_\text{C}}}{V_T}=\frac{I_{_\text{E}}}{V_T}\cdot\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}=\frac1{r_e^{\,'}}\cdot\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\$, which is often easier to use.)

So, instead of a physical emitter resistance that the tiny voltage wiggle applies to, we have \$r_e^{\,'}\$. And we can use it to estimate the collector current change.

Let's call the tiny base voltage wiggle as \$v_b\$. Then the tiny emitter current wiggle is \$i_e=\frac{v_b}{r_e^{\,'}}\$. This leads to a tiny collector current wiggle of \$i_c=\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\cdot i_e\$. And that's multiplied by the collector resistor to work out the fact that the tiny collector voltage wiggle will be \$v_c=-R_{_\text{C}}\cdot i_c\$.

So the unloaded voltage gain is:

$$A_v=\frac{v_c}{v_b}=\frac{-R_{_\text{C}}\cdot i_c}{v_b}=\frac{-R_{_\text{C}}\cdot \frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\cdot i_e}{v_b}=\frac{-R_{_\text{C}}\cdot \frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\cdot \frac{v_b}{r_e^{\,'}}}{v_b}=-\frac{R_{_\text{C}}}{r_e^{\,'}}\cdot\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}=-R_{_\text{C}}\cdot g_m$$

(Which is why \$g_m\$ is so easy to use.)

EDIT:
When I'd answered earlier, I'd forgotten to add the development for including the emitter resistor.

Added now:

$$A_v=-\frac{R_{_\text{C}}}{r_e^{\,'}+R_{_\text{E}}}\cdot\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}=-\frac{R_{_\text{C}}\cdot g_m}{1+\frac{\beta+1}{\beta}\cdot R_{_\text{E}}\cdot g_m}$$

Answer (score 1):

Av = Rc/re' and this is true if there is no load.

When a load is added and there is a capacitor across RE then approximately Av = (Rc//RL)/re' I say approximately because the capacitor will not be a perfect short to ground and it will have some reactance at signal frequencies but this reactance can be approximated to 0 ohms for most practical gain calculations.

So the gain is calculated by dividing the resistance at the collector (Rc//RL) by the resistance at the emitter (re').

The output resistance is approximately equal to Rc and this output resistance has no effect on input resistance calculations.

The input resistance is equal to R1//R2//beta*re' again RE is taken to be shorted out by the emitter bypass capacitor.

beta*re' will dominate the input resistance as it is low compared to R1 and R2.